# Writing a product of transpositions as a 3-cycle.

Tags: number-theory

For the case that we have two transpositions equal to each other, say (a b) (a b) then how can I write the product as a product of 3 cycles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two identical transpositions will cancel each other out; similarly three identical $3$-cycles will cancel each other out. So, assuming you have at least three elements to permute, you can write
$$(a\ b)(a\ b) = (x\ y\ z)(x\ y\ z)(x\ y\ z) = e$$
for any $x,y,z$, and where $e$ represents the identity.

Comment: Ok Thank you so much.